# How do I convince my professor to let me retake an exam?

Tags: exams

I have missed my makeup exam this semester. We are given 3 chances at my university to pass a course, 1 regular, a retake and a third exam for those who failed the previous 2 ones. I missed the third exam because of work, and because I almost never able to keep up any schedule.

I wrote an email to my professor to let me retake it, but because I wrote my email at the same time as the exam was, my professor deems it unfair to give me another chance in this.

If I was not a problem student I would agree with his decision, but I spent half a year in a psychiatric ward because I was unable to visit any kind of community, and in this very semester with the help of tranquilizers I almost attended all of my lectures.

Comment: So by *makeup* exam, you missed the exam that you were supposed to take because you missed an exam? You haven't stated why you missed the exam, which is rather crucial.  Do you have (or can you get) a medical certificate? That will be your best (and IMO only) chance.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, because it appears to be a question about a problem facing an undergraduate student.

Comment: @Ben Graduate students also miss exams

Comment: Which country is this in? Are there any regulations for cases of hardship? It's likely not even the professor's decision; you'll have to go the bureaucratic route. (Keep in mind that the way you explain it here, "I was working at the time of the exam", is not a particular strong case at first sight.)

Answer (score 13):

From what I can gather from the question and comments is that you missed the first exam, the resit, and the resit-resit due to some serious psychological issues and you have asked the Professor for a 4th shot and he said no. At this point there is no reason for you to try and convince the Professor to change his mind. Your university likely has a clear policy on missed exams (especially when you miss all three standard opportunities). You will either qualify for a 4th shot or not under the policy. You "student services" office will be able to help you file the proper paperwork.

Answer (score 12):

You should ask Disabled Students Services at your university for help. They can help with even recalcitrant faculty.

Comment: This is a lot easier if the student had already been to DSS to talk about his or her situation. And easier still if they have already talked with the professor about it.

Comment: @dmckee ...where by "talked with the professor about it", you mean "inform the professor that DSS has approved their request to retake the exam."  It's really none of the professor's business what disability the student might have.

Comment: If you missed the first 2 opportunities entirely, due to circumstances deemed valid by the DSS, rather than just failing them, you may have a case for retaking it. If you just didn't understand the material then retaking it again hoping to pass may not be in your best interests anyways (i.e. any future classes building on the material will be much more difficult). Either way, you (or an advocate of some sort) should have already communicated with DSS before classes even started so that they could be available to help.